# On the use of https in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I was learning Node.js and the way how Https module of Node.js works. So, imagine we have this code using https module:

```
var https = require('https');

https.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

So, all is ok but the question I wanted to ask is that why do we also need to get SSL certificate? Does it mean that the use of https module without SSL certificate does not make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To transfer data over the internet the protocol generally used is
  HTTP (Hypertext Transfer Protocol).
- But when we need data to be
  transferred in a secured way SSL certification is added to it to make
  it secure, HTTPS( Hypertext transfer protocol secure.)

This is a very good [reference](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate) to easily understand how the SSL works

Also, the use of https without SSL is not possible. check [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/343442/can-https-work-without-a-certificate)